# Assignment from incompatible pointer types, from struct in a header file

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I define a struct in file s.h

```
struct Scommand {
    int a;
    struct Scommand next;
}
```

and in my main.c I include s.h and have this code

```
struct Scommand *commandList=0;
struct SCommand *thisCommand;
thisCommand = commandList;
```

for some reason I always get the error "Assignment form incompatible pointer types" on the last line.  Can someone explain why?  This seems pretty simple

Comment: `struct SCommand` typo as `struct Scommand`

Comment: Wow do I feel stupid...you would THINK that the compiler might have complained about an undefined struct type?

Comment: Your definition of the struct will not compile. Fix this immediately!

Comment: @KirillKobelev correct. `next` change to `*next`.

Comment: @Telium mentioning an undefined struct type defines that struct type. (This is why I always use typedefs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 unrealated problems here:

Definition of the initial structure should look like:

```
struct Scommand {
    int a;
    struct Scommand *next;
}
```

Without that you are trying to insert the whole structure into itself. This makes  type definition recursive and this not allowed.

Second point. C and C++ have a concept of forward declaration:

```
struct Scmd *someCommand;
```

It might be surprising, but this line makes 2 things:

- Creates forward declaration for `Scmd` structure in the names table.
- Defines the variable `someCommand`.

In spite of the fact that this line looks like definition of the variable, in reality there are 2 definitions here. Now returning back to your code:

```
struct Scommand *commandList=0;
struct SCommand *thisCommand;
thisCommand = commandList;
```

The names of the structures are different because all names in C are case sensitive. The first one is already defined. The second one `SCommand` is defined in place. This is independent structure and it is not related to your original structure. This is the reason for the error. I agree that in this particular case the error is not very self explanatory. But well, it may appear in other cases where it might sound more appropriate.